# How to access controller name and action name form layout file in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I know to how to get controller name and action name from layout.phtml file so that i can make dynamic css.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try this:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

Comment: You can also get the module name the same way Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getModuleName()

Comment: I'm getting error as ouput for controllername and actioname, what might be wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't really have logic in your layout.

Best inject your css from your controller using the headlink container.

So in your controller...

```
$this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('custom_stylesheet.css');
```

And in your layout...

```
echo $this->headLink();
```

Simple as that! :)

Comment: I tend to think that the view should be setting the view assets such as stylesheets, scripts, etc, and not the controller. Using the placeholder view helpers is the way to go though.

Comment: I, on the other hand, tend to think that the view should be a canvas for the designers to... eerm design and that you should only try and echo stuff. Generic stuff should be defined in the init() method of the controller and specific stuff should be defined within the actions...

Comment: @AngelP What about where you use a context switch resulting in different view scripts for the same action? Surely you don't want to add stylesheets to the headLink placeholder if they're not going to be used. Hence, adding view assets in the view is the best place for it.

Comment: Different view scripts for the same action? Hmmmm... I like to keep things simple so I'd rather have multiple actions with their respective views to be honest. But that's me. ;) Of course, different applications need different solutions - so I'm not saying my solution is the right one, it's just the one I would follow...

Comment: @AngelP You've never used the magic of context switching, especially the `AjaxContext` helper? You're seriously missing out ;)

Comment: Ah! I just had a look at it now. Interesting but haven't had the need to use it so far. Thanks for the heads up anyway! ;)

Answer (score 0):

for finding controller name and action name in zend use this in controller

```
   Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName()
   Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getActionName()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this >baseUrl().'path to your css file without public folder'); 
?>
```